# How to disable Perl 6 REPL creating .precomp

Tags: raku, rakudo

Every time I run `perl6` to enter the `REPL` mode, it creates a `.precomp` directory, which also slows down the appearance of the prompt. If the `.precomp` directory already exists, the prompt appears almost immediately, otherwise `perl6` takes several seconds to create it.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it does that always? I just started it in a clean directory, and it didn't actually create anything. Does it happen when you're already in a module? To be sure, I'm not sure it's the interpreter the one that creates that...

Comment: @jjmerelo That's the case, and that's why I added a screenshot. I'm neither in a module, nor in a module (sub)folder. It's really very strange.

Comment: the thing is that I can't reproduce it. Maybe because I haven't installed Linenoise yet. Let me check.

Comment: No, still nothing with Linenoise and other modules installed... It might be that some module that is uploaded automatically is creating it.

Comment: @jjmerelo On Monday I'll check on my other computers, I suppose I have it only on one for unknown reason...

Comment: I'm also loading some modules and getting out, and nothing, there's no .precomp created. That is actually a CompUnit cache. It is created by the compiler with precomputed stuff when you read the source of something for the first time. If you're loading a module from a file, it might create it. But I don't see (and can't reproduce) how it would be created always.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if you have a `PERL6LIB` environment variable set, and if it contains `.`. I can produce exactly the behavior you're encountering if I set that. The solution is to clear that from your `PERL6LIB`.

Comment: it works!! Don't know how this dot appeared there. :)